# How do I generate video with a particular resolution in RAD-NeRF?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, video-processing

I am currently working on the RAD-NeRF project. I want to generate images at a different resolution than the trained one.

While using the Marco Rubio's pre-trained example, it generates videos at 620x620. However, I want to reduce this resolution to let's say 128x128 to improve the fps. Right now, I am getting about 24 fps using A100. I want to make it above 40 fps to be safe in production
Can you please help?

RAD-NeRF: https://github.com/ashawkey/RAD-NeRF

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.